# Select pairs of value from 2 columns from table A and insert it into another table B in random order

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm developping a quiz app, and for this I use 2 different tables:

- One is "question", where there are questions and answers
- the other one is "answer_quizz_user" with a unique id depending on the candidate, where I have exactly the same column than "question", with the answer in a random order.

My goal is to show the same question with the same answer in a random order, and to save it in the db like this.

[This is what my table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQhWA.png)
I would like to select the column by pair

(answer"X"_right_answer is a boolen which mean right or wrong answer):

(`answer1`,`answer1_right_answer`),

(`answer2`,`answer2_right_answer`),

(`answer3`,`answer3_right_answer`),

(`answer4`,`answer4_right_answer`),

(`answer5`,`answer5_right_answer`),

(`answer6`,`answer6_right_answer`)

to shuffle it, and insert it in "answer_quizz_user".

I tried different things like :

for ($n=1; $n <=6 ; $n++) {
INSERT INTO `answer_quizz_user` SELECT 
  `answer".$n."` FROM `question` 
  WHERE `question_question` = "q1" 
  ORDER BY RAND()}

but none worked. I have absolutely no idea how to manage this select->insert.  I know that I should have done another table for answers, but now it's too late, the app is almost finish, I just need this random part...

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english..

Comment: are you willing to change/update your schema?

Comment: Hi, yes I can, but there is a big chance that it impacts a lot of function in different files, but if you have any idea i take it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, although your database structure is quite bad. Next time use a separate table for your answers.

It isn't a copy-and-paste solution (I would needed to know more about your code to do that), but I hope it will be enough to set you on the right path.

The basic idea is, you get your pairs from the db, put them in an array, use php's built-in [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function, then insert your rows.

```
//  Gets the required row from database
$query = "select * from question where question_question = 'q1';";
$result = $db->query($query);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $question = $result->fetch_assoc();

    //  Create an array with the pairs
    $pairs = array();
    for($n = 1; $n <= 6; $n++) {
        $pairs[] = array(
            'Answer'    => $question['answer' . $n],
            'IsRight'   => $question['answer' . $n . '_right_answer'],
        );

    }

    //  Arrange pairs in random order
    shuffle($pairs);

    //  Insert the new rows
    foreach($pairs as $pair) {
        $query = "insert into answer_quizz_user values ('" . $pair['Answer'] . "', '" . $pair['IsRight'] . "');";
        $db->query($query);

    }

}
```

I hope, I could be of any help.

Comment: Hi Derenir, and thanks for your help !
I have this error Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$num_rows

Comment: Sorry about that, I wrote the database queries using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) connector, not [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). If you using PDO, change the queries accordingly.

Comment: Hi, again. So I tried your code and it works perfectly !! Thx a lot for your help !!

Comment: I'm glad, I could help. You can appreciate it by accepting and upping my answer. :)

Comment: You can't see it because of my lack of reputation "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.", but I did it ;) Thanks again !